# Java math power method

Tags: java, math, coordinates

Can anyone tell me why I'm not getting the correct answer trying to find the distance of x1, x2, y1, y2 below is the line of code that isn't working for me

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2));
```

Results:

Enter location of x1: 4

Enter location of x2: 0

Enter location of y1: 2

Enter location of y2: 0

distance: 4.47213595499958

As you can see I'm getting 4 when it should be 2 my workaround was simply multiplying but I'm still curious why I can't get it too work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x1, x2, y1, y2;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter location of x1: ");
    x1 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter location of x2: ");
    x2 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter location of y1: ");
    y1 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter location of y2: ");
    y2 = scan.nextDouble();

    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2-y1, 2));

    System.out.println("distance between: " +distance);


}
```

}

Comment: Why do you think the answer is supposed to be 2? The correct answer is the one you are getting.

Comment: It's 4.47213595499958 when it should be 4.47213595499958 actually,

Comment: The distance between (4, 2) and (0, 0) is 4.472. Check that the order of your inputs is what you expect it to be. Coordinates are (x1, y1) and (x2, y2).

Comment: Maybe you want distance from (x1, x2) to (y1, y2)? In that case, you want Math.pow(y1 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - x2, 2)

Comment: You took the square root of 20.  By the way, you ended up squaring negative numbers, which may not be intended.

Comment: Yes that worked for me @muzzlator

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP's question is related to Math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your code is right and you are just thinking of the math wrong. The distance between (4,2) and (0,0) should be 4.47... Your input to get a distance of 2 should be (4,0) and (2,0).

Make sure to double check those tests!

Answer (score 0):

If this helps, you're missing a ')'

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) ...
```

should be

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2)) ...
```

in order to compile correctly